# Custom login page in SharePoint 2016 On-prem not working

Tags: sharepoint-server, 2016, custom-login-page

I am trying to add a custom login page for SharePoint 2016 On-premise application. Below are the steps I followed:

1. Created one LoginPage.html page for UI.
2. Copied the page to /16/templates/layouts/ folder.
3. Central Admin-> Web application -> Authentication Providers -> Selected Custom login URL and gave URL as  */_layouts/15/LoginPage.html*
   -> Save
4. Updated `web.config` file with below code:

```
    <authentication mode="Forms">
        <forms loginUrl="/_layouts/15/LoginPage.html" />
    </authentication>
```

5. iisreset

Now, when I open the (dev)application URL http://servername:1234/sites/CustomSite, home page is opening, instead of Loginpage.html.

Can someone please help me understand, what I did wrong here?

Note: I created this simple solution, after googling.
Any help is highly appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This issue got fixed by adding a **`~`** before /_layouts/

```
<authentication mode="Forms">
        <forms loginUrl="~/_layouts/15/LoginPage.html" />
    </authentication>
```